# how do I use this RouteComponentProps in react hooks

Tags: reactjs

There is RouteComponentProps

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<
    Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {},
    C extends StaticContext = StaticContext,
    S = H.LocationState
> {
    history: H.History<S>;
    location: H.Location<S>;
    match: match<Params>;
    staticContext?: C;
}
```

using state I would do

```
class Example extends React.PureComponent<
  RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }>,
  State
>
```

I am not sure how I would convert that to using hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the example of using React hook and the `react-router-dom` package.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"; 
    
//hook example
const Example = () => {
      const params = useParams(); //retreive params you need
      
      console.log(params) 
 
      return (
         <div>
          //...other code
        </div>
      );
}

export default App;
```